# Check if Array exist in object Mongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have this schema for my book model and the NoOfLikes is supposedly storing user ids that liked a book as an array and also the date when it is added in that array for sorting

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

 noOfLikes : [{
    title: String
    user_id: String,
    dateLiked:{
        type:{type: Date,
               default: Date.now
             }
    }
    }],
})
```

and when i select a book it should go something like this

```
[  
  title: //title of book
  NoOfLikes[
     { 
      user_id: //id of the user who liked
      dateLiked: //date when it is added
     },

     {
      user_id: //id of other user who liked
      dateLiked: //date when it is added
     }
]
```

Now in my api im already sending the id of the book that the user likes and also the user id

```
const { id } = req.params;
```

and selected the book in the database

```
const book = await Book.findById(id);
```

I also have the userid that liked which is sent by my middleware and is stored in variable (_id)

Now I want to check if the _id of user already exist in the array of that book object that is already selected

```
 const index = book.noOfLikes.findIndex({ noOfLikes: {
    $elemMatch: {
      user_id: String(_id)
        }
      }   
    });
```

but im getting error  is not a function //well because its definitely not a function

How can I do this properly?

I want to also check if the userid(_id) already exist in that array of object and if not i want to push it inside the object , else filter the object array and remove that user id in array

```
//not sure if this will work

if (index === -1) {
      book.noOfLikes.push(_id);
   } 
else {
     book.noOfLikes = book.noOfLikes.filter((id) => id !== String(_id));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use query like follwoing

```
db.collection.find({
  title: "title of book"
},
{
  NoOfLikes: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$NoOfLikes",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this.user_id",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QOG4ePAMgdU)**

Comment: hello I tried your code to somoething like this
const bookid = id
   const userid = _id
   console.log( id)
   console.log(_id)
   const index =   await Book.find({
   _id: bookid
   },
   {
   noOfLikes: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$noOfLikes",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this.user_id",
           toString(userid)
        ]
      }
     }
   }
   })
but i still get result even if theres no matching _id in the array